# CSS Filters not applying to canvas element when the slider value changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas, react-hooks

#### Issue

Basically, I'm creating a photo editor using React.js

The user uploads a single image, then will be able to use the toolbar. Selecting the filters tool, it'll be opened a toolbar at the right with each effect. The problem is: if I try to change the slider (input of type range), it'll not work. On the other hand, if I try to apply just a single effect, it works.

[image: This is a representation of the issue]

#### Code

`components/Toolbar/Right/options.json` -> Here you'll find just each option with its properties, values (min and max).

```
[
  {
    "property": "brightness",
    "value": 100,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "contrast",
    "value": 100,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 200
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "saturate",
    "value": 100,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 200
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "grayscale",
    "value": 0,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "sepia",
    "value": 0,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "invert",
    "value": 0,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "hue-rotate",
    "value": 0,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 360
    },
    "unit": "deg"
  }
]
```

`components/FileUploader/index.js` ->

```js
function FileUploader() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
  const selectedFilter = options[activeTool];

  const onFileChange = e => {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      let imageFile = new Image();
      imageFile.onload = () => {
        const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        canvas.width = imageFile.width;
        canvas.height = imageFile.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.filter =  'blur(1.5rem)';
        ctx.drawImage(imageFile, 0, 0);
      }
      imageFile.src = e.target.result;
      setUploadedImageUrl(imageFile.src);
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])

    setIsDragging(false);
    setIsUploading(false);
  }

  // Get slider value according to the tools
  const handleSliderChange = ({ target }) => {
    setOptions(prevOptions => {
      return prevOptions.map((option, index) => {
        if (index !== activeTool) return option
        return { ...option, value: target.value }
      })
    })
  }

  // Get CSS filters and return as a object
  const handleImageStyling = () => {
    const filters = options.map(option => {
      return `${option.property}(${option.value}${option.unit})`
    })

    return filters.join(' ')
  }

  return (
    {/* If the upload finished and the filters tool is open... */}
      {uploadedImageUrl && (
        <Slider
          min={selectedFilter?.range.min}
          max={selectedFilter?.range.max}
          value={selectedFilter?.value}
          handleChange={handleSliderChange}
        />
      )}
  )
}
```

In this file, there are multiple functionalities, but let's focus just on what is really important and connected to the filters. You see that I get the options and pass into a `useState`, and also get the current option into a `const`.

The `onFileChange` function basically just get, read, and handle the image on upload, which is also connected to the canvas.

The `handleSliderChange` is just to get the current value based on the active option.

The `handleImageStyling` just gets all the filters and converts them into a single string, splitting it with space.

The problem is that the `handleImageStyling` function doesn't work as expected when called into the `ctx.filter`. I'd like to thank you for any kind of answer that can help me with this issue

Comment: Are you simply asking where/how to later access `ctx.filter` to update the canvas?

Comment: I wouldn't say simply, because I already tried almost everything. The problem is when the slider value change (not working)

Comment: What is the issue then? What are you asking? Is the `options` not updating as expected? Your question is unclear. Please explain what isn't working and how you expect it to work.

Comment: Mb I didn't explain well on my question, but the problem is that the `handleImageStyling` function should work on the `ctx.filter`, right? Because it is just getting the current value and passing it into a string. But, when the value changes on the slider, it doesn't update the filter.

Comment: The `handleImageStyling` return value appears to be valid for CSS filters. Where do you update the canvas' filter style? With the blur filter you have hardcoded, if you examine the DOM in the browser and manually write in a multi-filter there does it work as expected?

Comment: When you apply `ctx.filters` into a canvas is different from just applying "inline" styles, so it doesn't "show up" on the DOM. But... I already tried to apply multiple filters to the code and worked perfectly (e.g. `ctx.filter = 'blur(1.5rem) brightness(-50%)'`). The problem is when the value is changing (input of type range)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227169/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-esau-morais).